# Carrierwave Cropping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have an CarrierWave ImageUploader which creates a couple of versions of an original image that need to be cropped based on values in my model (crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, and crop_h).

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  ...
  version :t do
    process :cropper
    process :resize_to_fill => [75, 75]
  end
  ...
  def cropper
    manipulate! do |img| 
      img = img.crop "#{model.crop_x}x#{model.crop_y}+#{model.crop_w}+#{model.crop_h}"
      img
    end 
  end

end
```

The problem that I'm having is that I need to calculate some default cropping values if we don't have any set but I don't know where to put this logic. I tried putting this in my Photo model (which the uploader is mounted to) in a before_validation but this seems to be called after the cropper function has executed. I'm thinking that It either needs to be in the ImageUploader file, or in some callback that occurs before the thumbs are created.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985079/carrierwave-crop-specific-version

Comment: check this latest RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
process :cropper

def cropper
  manipulate! do |img|
    if model.crop_x.blank?
      image = MiniMagick::Image.open(current_path)
      model.crop_w = ( image[:width] * 0.8 ).to_i
      model.crop_h = ( image[:height] * 0.8 ).to_i
      model.crop_x = ( image[:width] * 0.1 ).to_i
      model.crop_y = ( image[:height] * 0.1 ).to_i
    end
    img.crop "#{model.crop_w}x#{model.crop_h}+#{model.crop_x}+#{model.crop_y}"
  end 
end
```

I'm running code equivalent to that in one of my apps.

Comment: I think you may have a small typo, whereby the first model.crop_y should be model.crop_h

Comment: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 3, 4, or 5))`. I think your `img.crop` is not the same as mine...

Comment: @AlexC it's `crop` from `MiniMagick`, you might be using `RMagick` or smth else

Comment: @faron, thanks but that question is getting really outdated for me now :p.

Comment: For RMagick, pass in the arguments for crop: `crop!(x, y, w, h)`